# Create icon inside of input with bootstrap and cakePHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, input

I have this cakePHP code:

```
<?php

  echo $this->Form->input('about_me',
         array('label'  => __l('About Me'),
               'class'  => 'form-control',
               'before' => '<div class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon input-icon-show"></i>',
               'after'  => '</div>',
               array('escape' => false)
         )
       );
?>
```

I would like the output to be (indented for readability):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group form-group-icon-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
  <label>About me</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Write something" type="text" />
 </div>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was like this:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-icon-right">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
    <?= $this->Form->input('about_me', [
        'div' => false,
        'label' => 'About me',
        'placeholder' => 'Write something',
    ];?>
</div>
```

I usually set `'label' => false`, used the CakePHP function only for the input field and customized the structure in pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Skatch's answer is good, but you would need to modify it further to make sure it takes into account validation. If you don't use the form helper for the wrapping div you don't get the `error` and `required` classes generated for you where appropriate.

It looks like you're almost there with your example code. However, rather than set the `<div>` in the `after` and `before` properties use the `div` property to define the `<div>` class:-

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('about_me',
     array('label'  => __l('About Me'),
           'class'  => 'form-control',
           'before' => '<i class="fa fa-user input-icon input-icon-show"></i> ',
           'div'  => 'form-group form-group-icon-left',
           'placeholder' => 'Write something'
        )
   );
?>
</div>
```

You can also define the `placeholder` as a property of the input as shown. You shouldn't need to use `'escape' => false`.

Comment: @cashtrader glad it worked. Please accept my answer so that others searching the site can quickly find the solution to your question. :-)